# Using Regex.Split to remove anything non numeric and splitting on -

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I'm not sure why but for some reason The Regex Split method is going over my head. I'm trying to look through tutorials for what I need and can't seem to find anything.

I simply am reading an excel doc and want to format a string such as `$145,000-$179,999` to give me two strings. `145000` and `179999`. At the same time I'd like to prune a string such as `'$180,000-Limit` to simply `180000`.

```
var loanLimits = Regex.Matches(Result.Rows[row + 2 + i][column].ToString(), @"\d+");
```

The above code seems to chop `'$145,000-$179,999` up into 4 parts: `145`, `000`, `179`, `999`. Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions match exactly character by character (there's no knowledge of the concept of a "number" or a "word" in regular expressions - you have to define that yourself in your expression).  The expression you are using, `\d+`, uses the character class `\d`, which means any digit 0-9 (and `+` means match one or more).  So in the expression `$145,000`, notice that the part you are looking for is not just composed of digits; it also includes commas.  So the regular expression finds every continuous group of characters that matches your regular expression, which are the four groups of numbers.

There are a couple of ways to approach the problem.

1. Include `,` in your regular expression, so `(\d|,)+`, which means match as many characters in a row that are *either* a digit or a comma.  There will be two matches: `145,000` and `179,999`, from which you can further remove the commas with `myStr.Replace(",", "")`. ([**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/oGDruU))
2. Do as you say in the title, and remove all non-numeric characters.  So you could use `Regex.Replace` with the expression `[^\d-]+` - which means match anything that is not a digit or a hyphen - and then replace those with `""`.  Then the result would be `145000-179999`, which you can split with a simple non-regular-expression split, `myStr.Split('-')`, to get your two parts. ([**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/aBN1b8))

Note that for your second example (`$180,000-Limit`), you'll need an extra check to count the number of results returned from `Match` in the first example, and `Split` in the second example to determine whether there were two numbers in the range, or only a single number.

Comment: You sir, are awesome. Thank you very much. The little "DEMO" you put in there was incredibly helpful. Thanks for your knowledge!

Comment: @JustinPeterson: See note.  You'll need some special logic to handle the second case where there is only one number.

Comment: Definitely. Well I'm adding these numbers to a list so I'm checking if there is a second value. On that check I simply just add in a default value if the count < 2

Answer (score 1):

you can try to treat each string separately by spiting it based on - and extraction only numbers from it

```
 ArrayList mystrings = new ArrayList();
 List<string> myList = Result.Rows[row + 2 + i][column].ToString().Split('-').ToList();

 foreach(var item in myList)
 {

     string result = Regex.Replace(item, @"[^\d]", "");
     mystrings.Add(result);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using RegEx is to use the built in string and char methods in the DotNet framework. Assuming the input string will always have a single hypen:

```
string input = "$145,000-$179,999";

var split = input.Split( '-' )
        .Select( x => string.Join( "", x.Where( char.IsLetterOrDigit ) ) )
        .ToList();

string first = split.First(); //145000
string second = split.Last(); //179999
```

1. first you split the string using the standard `Split` method
2. then you create a new string by selectively taking only Letters or Digits from each item in the collection: `x.Where...`
3. then you join the string using the standard `Join` method
4. finally, take the first and last item in the collection for your 2 strings.